# Conflict in defining a variable ina typeclass implementation

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to implement Eq class type for the following data:

```
data Pair a = Pair a a
instance Eq a => Eq (Pair a) where
    (==) (Pair x x) (Pair y y) = (x == y)
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Conflicting definitions for ‘y’ in ....

My questions:

1. I think I am doing things "By the book", so why I am getting this error?
2. If I am re-defining `y`, why there isn't a similar error for `x`?
3. Where is this "re-definition" in the above code?

Comment: Hint: what would `x` and `y` be if you evaluated `Pair 1 2 == Pair 1 2`?

Comment: Hmmm! Is it possible to have Pair 1 2 in the first place. Maybe my mistake is thinking that the 2 as in the data constructor have the same value.

Comment: I re-implemented the last line of my code as:
        (==) (Pair x y) (Pair z m) = (x == z && y == m)
Now there is no error.

Thanks leftaroundabout.

Comment: Exactly. They have the same _type_, that's what `data Pair a = Pair a a` says; but clearly most types permit more than a single value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the following call is being made:

```
(Pair 1 2) == (Pair 3 4)
```

The value 1 will be assigned to x at this point:

```
(==) (Pair x...
```

At this point x is being reassign to the value 2 which is not allowed:

```
(==) (Pair x x...
```

Hence the error

As for the answer to your second question, you should have gotten an error for both x, and y, like so:

```
Test.hs:6:16:
    Conflicting definitions for `x'
    Bound at: Test.hs:6:16
              Test.hs:6:18
    In an equation for `=='

Test.hs:6:27:
    Conflicting definitions for `y'
    Bound at: Test.hs:6:27
              Test.hs:6:29
    In an equation for `=='
```

Comment: I agree. While my re-implementation or what @vanson-samuel suggests makes the compiler happy (no mistake), I am still not clear about the error message itself: Where is the re-definition happening in my first code?

Comment: Yes, thanks @vanson-samuel. With the example you are citing it is more clear now where the re-definition is occurring.